# Dojo / RequireJS obfuscate / minify modules in .Net build system for Web Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dojo, requirejs, obfuscation

I'm working on complex web app that is using the dojo toolkit for organization of the js files which is basically a requireJS module loader.

I'm trying to figure it out how can i obfuscate all of my (require/define) modules in the .net web app... with [YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com) i can minify all of the modules but i cannot obfuscate them because every module exposes some methods that are used in another modules...

I have read that maybe r.js optimizer using NodeJS will do the trick (because will walk the entire dependency tree, including each module that it finds) but the build process of the project that i work on is very complex and it's automated... all of 150+ .NET projects including the web app are build and deployed with separate build system and i need to automate the obfuscation of the js files.So i need some .net assailable that can obfuscate js files that are organized with Dojo/requireJS

Thanks